# Can't Install Medilazar theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, customization

I am working on a project with Medilazar wordpress theme, with functionality pharmacy feature. I got a notification "There are no predefined import files available in this theme. Please upload the import files manually" when I use 1 click import demo.
How can I solve it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using this Medilazar theme : (https://themeforest.net/item/medilazar-pharmacy-woocommerce-wordpress-theme/29688656)

Because I get the same issues as you. And for a little time, I get the support and now it works. You can follow:

- Ensure your server admin or Cpanel support: enable allow_url_fopen = 1
- Server support Json file
- Check permission as this guide: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ftp/change-permissions/

Hope that helps you well.